# confusion about operator overload in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, operator-overloading

I define a class to wrap raw pointer, so the pointer can be delete automatically. Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
class Entity
{
private:
    std::string e_name;
public:
    Entity():e_name("unknown"){}
    void whoami() {
        std::cout << e_name;
    }
};
class ScopePointer
{
private:
    Entity *_e;
public:
    ScopePointer(Entity *e) : _e(e) {}
    ~ScopePointer() { delete _e; }
    Entity *operator->() { return _e; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ScopePointer p(new Entity());
    p->whoami();
}
```

It works well but I quite don't understand how `p->whoami();` works.
I mean the operator -> overload in ScopePointer should work like below

```
p.operator->()->whoami();or p->->whoami();
```

the first `->` should return Entity* and the next `->` call class method.
why only one -> can make it work ?

Comment: "*why only one -> can make it work ?*" I don't really understand what you mean. It works because that's how it's *designed* to work. The entire point of allowing overloading of `->` is to allow a type to mimic certain pointer functionality. If it didn't work this way, it'd be useless.

Comment: What would be the benefit of it to work like you suggest it should?

Comment: The `->` operator is a bit "magical" - it "keeps going" as long as the result is something with a `->` operator.

Comment: Side note: for `ScopePointer`, consider also overload `operator*`, or the dereference/indirection operator. Or you can simply use `std::unique_ptr<Entity>`

Answer (score 6):

I hope that this quote from the C++ 14 Standard will help to understand how the operator works.

The C++ 14 Standard (13.5.6 Class member access, p #1)

> An expression x->m is interpreted as (x.operator->())->m for a class
> object x of type T if T::operator->() exists and if the operator is
> selected as the best match function by the overload resolution
> mechanism.

So the overloaded operator in fact is a "prefix expression" of the built-in operator-> that supplies a pointer used in the built-in operator.

Answer (score 3):

> I quite don't understand how `p->whoami();` works

There is an exception to the ordinary rules of operators for `->`, such that you only need one `->`. The language requires the implementation recursively evaluate `operator->` until it finds a pointer object, instead of a object of some class type.

From [`[over.ref]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ref)

> A *class member access operator function* is a function named `operator->` that is a non-static member function taking no parameters. For an expression of the form
>
> *postfix-expression*->template<sub>opt</sub>*id-expression*
>
> the operator function is selected by overload resolution ([over.match.oper]), and the expression is interpreted as
>
> (*postfix-expression*.`operator->()` ) -> template<sub>opt</sub> *id-expression*